# Trimming a Base64 string to only display first X amount of pages in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Not aware if this is possible but I have a Base64 string which is around 50 pages long. To display this, I have converted it to a PDF within the Controller and then displayed this as a PDF using  on the front-end.

I'm wondering if there is a way to trim the Base64 string in C# to only show the first 15 pages?

Comment: *Strings* have no pages. Printing or displaying text on screen or a document requires calculating the page, line size, line wrap locations etc and then *rendering* that text one page at a time

Comment: Could you give more detail about why you want to display base64 in the frontend anyway? That's rarely going to be useful IMO. If you can give more context, we'll be able to help you more.

Comment: So I have a big list of PDFs and once the user clicks one, it populates an area on the page with an <iframe> tag that displays the actual PDF.

Comment: Base64 text is unreadable by *humans* anyway. You could just break it apart in chunks of 2000 characters (80x25), or any other chunk size you like, and simply display it on the UI. You don't need PDF for this

Comment: @TS07 this has nothing to do with Base64. The big list is a list of URLs pointing to the documents, not the document contents themselves. The frame you describe displays whole documents, not single pages

Comment: @TS07 Unless you want to create image URLs from individual pages?

Comment: I'm still very confused how base64 comes into this. Are you really saying that you just want to serve the first 15 pages of *each PDF*? If so, that sounds like this is about using some PDF software (e.g. iTextSharp) to delete pages 16 onwards, then cache the result of that. I'd expect you to serve that as a regular PDF file though - no base64 required.

Comment: It's stored in the database as binary and I then convert it to Base64 within the Controller. Even if I left the extracted data as Binary, my question would remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing so would likely make the Base64 string or the underlying binary data unreadable:

- You can only cut the Base64 exactly every 4 characters, wich represent 3 bytes of the original binary. Anywhere else makes the String non-decodeable on those last characters (and most decoders will fold outright, because they asume the Base64 String is damaged).
- And depending on wich (file) format the binary put into Base64 represents, there is a high chance partial binary can not be interpreted.

Base64 was invented specifically to get random binary data across media, that only support ASCII characters reliably. Like Emails and HTML inline, for example. It is basically a 6/8 encoding.

You said that this data Represent PDF. It is honestly wierd that large files were stored in Base64 to begin with. However PDF does have supprot for this: https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/interlacing-field-order.html

Asuming those were intended for Online Distributin, there is a good chance those PDF do have [interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps)) enabeled. So they could be partially read - the text is in front, then the interlaced images are "smeard" across the rest of the binary.

But it is usually better to just make a preview image the hard way, store that in the DB and leave it at that.

Comment: That makes sense. My guess would've been that I could've used a library to help me extract the pages one by one but I understand why this isn't possible. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @TS07: PDF is kinda unique among the Document formats, in that it does support interlacing on the document level. But as interlacing tends to add a lot of read and size overhead, it is not enabeled by default.